# Copy-Paste code from Sublime to PHP Storm went wrong

Tags: phpstorm, sublimetext3

I'm new to html/css/js/php and i'm trying to create a site.I started working my html/css on a simple editor (Sublime-i know not the best idea),but in the meanwhile i started using PHP Storm. In order to get the pages i have made i copied the html content from Sublime and i pasted them in a new PHP file in PHP Storm (i did the same with the css). It turned out that transition went horrible and when i preview it is completely distrorted. Any ideas on what could have been so terribly wrong?

Comment: When asking a question on the internet, please remember that we cannot peek your monitor over your shoulders.

Comment: I have that in mind, but is not a matter of code since it's copy-paste from an editor to an IDE. Via editor it works via IDE it doesn't. I was looking for something i might not know about PHP Storm, maybe a setting option?

Comment: Hmmm... Do you mean a "Distort preview" setting or something? :-?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before when I was trying to decide what to use sublime, phpstorm, and komodo edit. You need to copy the code across into a new .html or .php file. I can't recall which one does it but the file extension has something different that stops it.